# Error "ABSOLUTE path INSTALL DESTINATION forbidden (by caller)" when generate installer for Windows by using CPack NSIS

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I´m trying to run packet generator within a VS project, it crashes while compiling because of the use of absolute path on installation from Targets and Files.

```
 ABSOLUTE path INSTALL DESTINATION forbidden (by caller): ...
```

I checked twice and all installation directories are relative. I set quite a lot of variables as sub-folders of `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}` (which should be relative) such as:

```
set(INSTALL_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib)
set(EXT_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/ext)
...
```

does CMAKE/CPACK interpret those variables as absolute paths?
If so, is there a way to make CPack working properly with those variables?
How do I use CPack when sub-relative path are involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see, the ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} is interpreted as an ABSOLUTE path, from there all sub-folder of it will be rejected.

To avoid this problem I surrounded the install variables in if else blocks, and if it is the case of packaging then a relative folder will be used as follows:

```
if(PACK)
   set(INSTALL_DIR bin)
   set(LIB_DIR bin/lib)
   set(EXT_DIR /bin/ext)
   ...
else(PACK)
   set(INSTALL_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
   set(LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib)
   set(EXT_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/ext)
   ...
endif(PACK)
```

this solves it, but it is really dirty, waiting for a better function on new CPack version.

ciao

Answer (score 1):

This fatal error is meant to tell you installation root should be specified at the moment when user executes the installer.  I guess somewhere in your cmake config might have code like this:

```
INSTALL (TARGET myApp DESTINATION ${SOME_INSTALL_PATH}/bin )
```

If you assign `SOME_INSTALL_PATH` an absolute path when cmake cache is generated, you incur the `CMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION` error, which gave you the `"ABSOLUTE path INSTALL DESTINATION forbidden (by caller)"` message.

To solve this problem, either always use relative path for installation `DESTINATION` or assign only package prefix to `SOME_INSTALL_PATH` variable.

For reference, following is the link to `INSTALL` command.
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION.html

There was also a similar question asked on the CMake mailing list.
http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2013-May/054656.html